# vim black box around text in windows terminal

Tags: vim, windows-terminal

my background has already disappeared but my text kinda like have this weird black box around them

[image]

So what I want to be is that the text doesn't have those black box around them I want to be the text also clear I don't know how to fix this in my vimrc

Comment: I see some with this black background, while some without. I suppose it was caused by syntax highlighting file or something?

Comment: ehhmm..., I see ..., is there any way to fix this?

Comment: And, by "my background is already disappeared", what you did before "disapper", and what caused this "disapper"? Try changing any syntax related settings, like `set ft=XXX` (XXX is another filetype's name) or `colorscheme` or `syntax on` in `_vimrc`, and redo all the action to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Oo okay ... I'll try it

Comment: yeah... you're right. It's because of the syntax highlighting